# UIScrollViewDelegate not working

Tags: iphone, uiscrollviewdelegate

Hello I'm trying to trigger a function when the user is scrolling the app.

Here is my code

I defined a class MyViewController which implements the UIScrollViewDelegate

```
@interface CircleViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
  UIScrollView *scroll;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIScrollView * scroll;

@end
```

Then, in the .m, in the ViewDidLoad I wrote :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scroll.delegate = self;
[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

NSInteger nbView = 3;


scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

for(int i = 0; i < nbView; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.height;

    UIView * vue = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, xOrigin,     self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    vue.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    [scroll addSubview:vue];
    [vue release];

}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,   self.view.frame.size.height * nbView);
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

And I define the trigger :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

When I run the app, I am able to scroll, but the scrollViewDidScroll never gets called.

Answer (score 6):

you are allocating the scroll view twice may be that what is causing the problem...
you just need to alloc  it once and then set the delegate.

Comment: The second allocation of scroll overrides the first one, and the delegate is lost.  You probably want to use [scroll setFrame:] instead of scroll= [[UIScrollView alloc]...] the second time, as alloc creates a new scroll view